# How can i go back to previous page by loading cache data through javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#

There is a scenario where we are searching collection of item and clicking on anyone item and after viewing i am coming back to previous page, So what is happening right now that all the data is again loading instead of taking previous results from cache/session, I also tried window.history.back() but It's also taking enough time to load collection of item.

Comment: You cannot control browser cache via javascript. I suggest to write custom caching\session logic

Comment: what kind of project is it a MVC or web api ?

Comment: it's mvc project and like i want to store the cache and then when i click on back for previous button then should take cached data instead of searching again all collection of data

Comment: I worked on this and found the solution with sessionStorage Javascript